# SharePoint 2010 profile synchronization AD to MOSS in BOTH Direction

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Our company want to setup a **User Profile Synchronization** on SharePoint 2010.

In **Manage User Properties** page, we can successfully configure a property to either import from AD to MOSS or export from MOSS to AD!

However, we want to configure some properties that allow synchronize in both direction, which is actual meaning of "Synchronize". We wonder if it was possible in MOSS 2010?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible OOTB. Each profile property can be synced in one direction only using SPS2010. If you want two-way synch then you need to use the full ForeFront Indentity Manager 2010.